# foreign key in django_models

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models

In pgAdmin I create my table :

[image: PgAdmin screenshot]

in this table there are 2 columns by "foreign key" and connect to column of other table:

[image: foreign key screenshot]

how to can create this table in django models?
"I use postgresql in django".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a `Gift` model like:

```
#  app/models.py

from django.conf import settings
from django.db import models

class Gift(models.Model):
    gift = models.CharField(50)
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='gift_set'
    )
    invited = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        null=True,
        related_name='invited_gift_set'
    )
```

Since you did not specify the "trigger", I wrote it with `CASCADE` for the `user_id` column, and `SET_NULLL` for the `invited_id` column.

Comment: Using [`python manage.py inspectdb`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/legacy-databases/) might also help to get to a working `models.py`.

Comment: @Jieter: well a potential problem is that not all databases have a Django model equivalent. For example if you add two foreign keys to the same column, then technically speaking that column refers to two models at the same time. My experience with such tools is that in the long end, they do more harm than good, since most people assume "everything is all right". It looks a bit like the old compiler-compilers where one had to fill in the missing elements manually. Changing a LALR parser according to some specs turns out to be quite complicated.